# Is there a method to save data in android App

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I built a unity game for android then I export my project and import it in  android studio but  when I install my game in my mobile it doesn't save any data
So I need to knew why this happen and how to solve it

I read about the permissions but I don't knew how I do it

Comment: try unity SaveGamePackage

Comment: How are you "saving your data"? In a file (what path, does that exist on Android?), in a database (does that exist /is that accessible on mobile)? Any errors? If not, is that because you ignore exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-do-i-save-progress-for-an-android-game.461446/

You can see the unity forum / see the documentation. I don't know what data you use, but I hope this will help you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).